# Pandas - df.size() error: 'numpy.int64' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using pandas, I'm trying to plot some data using:

```
df.size().unstack().plot(kind=barh)
```

but I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not callable
```

then I tried `df.size()` only and got the same error. Now I'm not sure what causes this because according to the documentation, `DataFrame.size()` should work fine. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one problem you need omit `()` in [`DataFrame.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.size.html), but output is scalar, so impossible call `unstack`:

```
df.size
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

a = df.size
print (a)
36
```

Maybe need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`GroupBy.size()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['F', 'B']).size().unstack()
print (df1)
B  4  5
F      
a  2  1
b  1  2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification! I just noticed that GroupBy.size() is different from df.size. I was following a tutorial from a book and this wasn't mentioned. Anyways, Thanks again! @jezrael

Comment: Glad can help. I first time use `df.size`, so first I think output is length of datarame ;) Good luck!